# product of two dataframes with new boolean column based on matched values in third dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following three dataframes:

```py
In [55]: df0
Out[55]: 
  m_id
0   m1
1   m2
2   m3
3   m4

In [56]: df1
Out[56]: 
  c_id
0   c1
1   c2
2   c3

In [57]: df2
Out[57]: 
  m_id  foo c_id
0   m1   42   c1
1   m2  101   c1
2   m2  309   c2
```

My goal is to determine, for each `m_id` from `df0`, in relation to ALL `c_id` from `df1`, which have a row in `df2` where `m_id` and `c_id` are both present resulting in a `present` column in this resulting dataframe.

Desired resulting dataframe something like:

```py
In [62]: df3
Out[62]: 
   m_id c_id    foo  present
0    m1   c1   42.0     True
1    m2   c1  101.0     True
2    m3   c1    NaN    False
3    m4   c1    NaN    False
4    m1   c2    NaN    False
5    m2   c2  309.0     True
6    m3   c2    NaN    False
7    m4   c2    NaN    False
8    m1   c3    NaN    False
9    m2   c3    NaN     True
10   m3   c3    NaN    False
11   m4   c3    NaN    False
```

I can see a naive approache that might:

1. for all `c_id` values in `df1`, copy `df0` to new dataframe `df_n#`
2. create new column `c_id` with `c_id` value
3. for each row in `df_n#`, determine if `m_id` + `c_id` in `df2` and write `True|False`
4. concat all `df_n#` dataframes (which in this scenario would be 3 of them) for final result

But I'm interested if there are better approaches that might leverage more pandas functionality.

It feels as though there might be an approach that is more akin to the following, but I'm unsure of syntax:

1. create dataframe of `df0` x `df1`
2. merge with `df2`, writing `True|False` to new `present` column where `df2` rows match both `m_id` and `c_id`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Pandas 1.2.0* you can use the cross join in `merge`:

```
df = df0.merge(df1, how='cross').merge(df2, on = ['m_id', 'c_id'], how='left')
```

Result:

```
   m_id c_id    foo
0    m1   c1   42.0
1    m1   c2    NaN
2    m1   c3    NaN
3    m2   c1  101.0
4    m2   c2  309.0
5    m2   c3    NaN
6    m3   c1    NaN
7    m3   c2    NaN
8    m3   c3    NaN
9    m4   c1    NaN
10   m4   c2    NaN
11   m4   c3    NaN
```

To add a boolean column:

```
df['present'] = df.foo.notna()
```

Result:

```
   m_id c_id    foo  present
0    m1   c1   42.0     True
1    m1   c2    NaN    False
2    m1   c3    NaN    False
3    m2   c1  101.0     True
4    m2   c2  309.0     True
5    m2   c3    NaN    False
6    m3   c1    NaN    False
7    m3   c2    NaN    False
8    m3   c3    NaN    False
9    m4   c1    NaN    False
10   m4   c2    NaN    False
11   m4   c3    NaN    False
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks!  Didn't know about the cross method for merge.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `product` from `itertools` to create a combination data frame and then merge that to `df2`

```
from itertools import product
# create a third frame that includes all combinations of df0 and df1
df3 = pd.DataFrame(product(df0['m_id'], df1['c_id']), columns=['m_id', 'c_id'])
# left merge df3 and df2 together on m_id and c_id
merge = df3.merge(df2, on=['m_id', 'c_id'], how='left')
# use np.where to create boolean values if there is a match
merge['present'] = np.where(merge['foo'].isna(), False, True)

   m_id c_id    foo  present
0    m1   c1   42.0     True
1    m1   c2    NaN    False
2    m1   c3    NaN    False
3    m2   c1  101.0     True
4    m2   c2  309.0     True
5    m2   c3    NaN    False
6    m3   c1    NaN    False
7    m3   c2    NaN    False
8    m3   c3    NaN    False
9    m4   c1    NaN    False
10   m4   c2    NaN    False
11   m4   c3    NaN    False
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  While I selected the other as the answer, I appreciate seeing this other way of doing it.